# Uncaught Error: process.binding is not supported (when developing in React, fluxible and electron)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, electron, fluxible

I was using React & fluxible & electron to work on on the app flows and it follows the standard react flow, i.e, `component -> action -> store -> component`

1. click on some React components and this triggers an `Action` in `ActionCreators`
2. `Action` will do `fs.readfileSync` and dispatch 'done' to the `store`
3. the React component will see the change in the `store` and renders the `component` again.

I failed at step 2 when I was about to read a file into the app. It gives me an error message saying:

```
Uncaught Error: process.binding is not supported
```

And I wonder if I did something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fs module will not work on the client. You should move file access to a place that is server only and expose it via an XHR endpoint. If you are using fluxible-plugin-fetchr you can do this within a service and call the service from your action creator.

Comment: actually in electron I can use fs somehow.  like `var fs = require('fs'); fs.readdir()` works just fine.  but if I transpile the code to es6 then the program just won't compile (my current situation..)

Comment: https://github.com/substack/brfs/issues/39 something similar but I am still trying to figure out if we have the same problem though.

Comment: Are you using webpack? The error message you're seeing looks like Webpack's `process` implementation, which does not support the `binding` method.

Comment: right now only browserify and gulp to pack stuff to bundle.js